# How to remove all items at a specified index in a nested list python

Tags: python

I have a list that contains some stuff similar to the below entry:
`[[1, 'Potato', 2, 'Bag'], [2, 'Banana, 1, 'Bunch']]`.
These elements represent in order the item's UPC, Name, Quantity, and unit type. What I want to do is delete all the items at a certain index to change the list from the above to `[[1, 'Potato', 2, 'Bag']]`. I tried a couple of methods, but I either used them wrong or they weren't supposed to be used there (I used del, pop, and remove). How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Did you try slicing?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: `del your_list[1]` should have worked here, can you show what you tried and the error you got / how it was different from your expected output?

Comment: As would `your_list.pop(index)`. Please see [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and provide a [mre]

Comment: `[start_index: last_index]` to an list. For example `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5][:3]` will produce `[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: oh that worked. I was using del wrong. Thank you!

Comment: @EliHarold that makes no difference. `del lst[index]` removes that element, regardless of the type of the element

Comment: I know. My page hadn't refreshed while I was typing that response. I'm responding to shriakhilc's comment.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi yes I know that, I thought they wanted to remove items from sublists.

Comment: It helps to show working code so we have variable names to reference.

Comment: Basically. My apologies for asking this question. I was using the del command incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

`del` works for your example

```
>>> data = [[1, 'Potato', 2, 'Bag'], [2, 'Banana', 1, 'Bunch']]
>>> del data[1]
>>> data
[[1, 'Potato', 2, 'Bag']]
```